# No dependencies found in Jaeger (openTelemetry-Go)

Tags: jaeger, open-telemetry, jaeger-client-go

I have a test implementation of the client and server.
[OpenTelemetry-Go](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go) and [Jaeger Exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/tree/main/exporters/jaeger) is used to collect statistics.
Also [otelGRPC](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/google.golang.org/grpc/otelgrpc) instrumentation is used.

**Reports working correctly:**
[image: 1]

**Detailed information:**
[image: 2]

**But dependencies not found:**
[image: 3]

**Yes, I know that i need to run a spark task:**

```
21/12/15 13:02:34 INFO CassandraDependenciesJob: Running Dependencies job for 2021-12-15T00:00Z: 1639526400000000 ≤ Span.timestamp 1639612799999999
21/12/15 13:02:34 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/12/15 13:02:41 INFO CassandraDependenciesJob: Storing dependencies into dependencies_v2
21/12/15 13:02:41 INFO CassandraDependenciesJob: Done, 0 dependency objects created
```

But for some reason this task can't find dependencies...

**Just in case, I connected zipkin:**
[image: 4]
And everything works in it!

**Version:**

- OS: mac
- Jaeger version: 1.29
- Deployment: Docker

As a result, **I don't know where to look for the problem**. The spark task does **not report errors** and simply exits with no dependencies found.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that, although the requests are grouped, they are not nested. It was because of the lack of nesting in this particular example that it was not possible to build a dependency graph.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).